# json photo path format in xcode

Tags: json, xcode

i have a jpg file in my database,
how can i used json/php build in my Xcode project?
my jpg link in php format like this:

```
[{"photo_path":"photo_path.jpg,"title":"test topic""]}
```

i know when i build "title" part,i can use NSString format,
but in "photo_path.jpg" part,did i use NSString also??

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * photo_path;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *detaillabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *photolabel;
```

and here is my json.m part:

```
- (void) retrieveData
{
  NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    HomeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i = 0; i < json.count; i++)
{
    NSString * titletopic = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSString * detailinfo = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"detail"];
    NSString * photo = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"photo_path"];
    NSString * dateinfo = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"date"];

    HomeDetail * home2 = [[HomeDetail alloc]initWithTitle:titletopic
                                                andDetail:detailinfo
                                            andPhoto_path:photo
                                                  andDate:dateinfo];

    [HomeArray addObject:home2];
}
[self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: You certainly provided some code but i don't understand what your question is... :\

Comment: i have some jpg file in my db,i want to show it but using json ,and i know NSString can't show what i need,i want to ask what NSObject i can used?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the path/url of your image in your database. By path I mean local path (if the image is stored locally) or URL if it's somewhere on the interwebz.

Fetch that URL whichever way pleases you (JSON is fine), and make your way through the JSON to retrieve the `NSString` of that URL.

( you appear to have that all done already, in your `NSString *photo`

Though i suggest you rename "photo" with `photoPath` or something more clear because the photo name strongly suggests it's already an image, which it isn't yet :)

Then simply apply this where you need the `UIImage` object:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:photo];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data cache:NO];
```

You can then add it to an imageview using `setImage:` or `.image`

Comment: Where can i add these code??
I don't know where can i paste them~
sorry and thanks

Comment: Wherever you need to load your image. For example in viewDidLoad of the relevant controller.

Make sure you understand the flow of your code, you need to understand when to load and where to load. Once you need the images, load them and display them :) (most probably in a viewDidLoad !)

Comment: i try to used your method,but i still can't get my database jpg to my Xcode...-_-

Comment: Can you show me the exact URL you're using for your jpg?

Comment: my jpg is saved in my php/json file ,it not only one photo,so i don't know how to show it to you...sorry

Comment: Well you need to check if your url is valid before trying to fetch its  contents.

Either use breakpoints and see what's in your url string or simply NSLog(); it. Then copy paste it in your browser and see if  you actually see the image.
If you have the image, then the code is client-side, if you don't , then its server-side (your php/json)

Comment: got it,let me try,Thanks

Comment: Once you have that, you can store it anywhere (if possible a database), but for the sake of testing you can skip that and just hard-code it.
And if it doesn't work then we can see from there.
If it works, then you just have to implement the DB which, if you've never done it, should take you about a day